# Nginx + php-fpm 502 bad gateway only on domain

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

I have centos server, it's configured with php and nginx, when I restart that time php file is not executing when i type ip address instead of domain address, it's working fine

nginx config for vhost

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name domainname.com;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://www.domainname.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name www.domainname.com;
  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http'){
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  root /home/global/domainname.com;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  access_log  /home/global/logs/access.log;
  error_log   /home/global/logs/error.log;

  location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_intercept_errors      on;
#proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
      #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      #fastcgi_index  index.php;
      #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      #include  fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/global/domainname.com$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your nginx config?

Comment: @Araw, config is added, please check the same

Comment: You only add `server_name www.domainname.com;`, you need to add `server_name your ip address here;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your ip address to your server in your nginx conf if you want to access your server by ip address.

```
server_name your_ip_address;
```